# Why does my mutable array become NULL in the prepareForSegue method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, null, uistoryboardsegue

I want to pass an array onto another class using storyboards, and I've prepared the following code, however, the log shows that the mutable array is null, where as this is clearly not the case (in another method, the log shows it is not null, it only becomes null when prepareForSegue gets called). Why is this?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"confirmSegue"]) {
        SBBookingConfirmation *bookingConfirmed=(SBBookingConfirmation*)segue.destinationViewController;
        NSLog(@"dates chosen - %@", self.dateChosen);    
        bookingConfirmed.confirmedTimings=self.dateChosen;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
dates chosen - (null)
```

Comment: How can we know why `dateChosen` is nil? You've only provided to references to it in your sample, and neither of them shed any light whatsoever on why.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, you are changing `self.dateChosen` somewhere else. This has nothing to do with `prepareForSegue:`.

Go back and check what you do before the segue is invoked (through IB or by method).

Comment: the only place where i change it is here,

    -(void)method:(NSMutableArray *)array{
        dateChosen=array;
        NSLog(@"The following has been copied %@", dateChosen);
    }

Comment: But it is nil before you use it. So you changed it somewhere else.

Comment: I see, but I didnt set it to nil anywhere myself, so how could this have happened?

Comment: @user1898662 Is your `-method:` method called anyplace? (That's an awful name for a method, btw.)

Comment: apart from being declared in the header file, nope

Comment: what is the attribute of your dateChosen? It should be strong. also, your "method" should use the setter to set it, ie self.dateChosen = array

Comment: @user1898662 Did you at least initialize `dateChosen` anyplace, with a NSMutableArray instance?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, your dateChosen property is of type strong:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *dateChosen;
//if you have an NSArray instead of NSMutableArray, use copy instead of strong
```

also in your "method" method (worst name ever!) , you should use the setter to set dateChosen:

```
-(void)method:(NSMutableArray *)array {
 self.dateChosen=array; //not dateChosen = array;
 NSLog(@"The following has been copied %@", self.dateChosen);
}
```

Finally, you need to initialize your array somewhere. If you never did something like

```
self.dateChosen = [NSMutableArray array];
```

or

```
self.dateChosen = <NON-NIL array pointer>
```

it is no wonder it would be nil.

On a side note: choose your method / variable names better. Don't call a method just "method".
If you use an array, it is usually better to name it in its plural form: date**s**Chosen, instead of dateChosen.